# Using only IF and else without other technique to loop a 2 -d array

Tags: python

I wish to try a use case that has been troubling me since last 2 years and now wish to solve my this problem.

Is there a way to loop through a 2d list without the use of any for loop or other method other than just IF-Else?

Example

I have a 2d list - [3][6] // the first and second could be changed randomly and if possible, I wish to have a limit to it.

```
x = 0
y = 0

Seriously I dont know how to start it so I dont have any method yet. But I will update it soon

Since x and be increase by 1 everytime so I thought maybe below could be used. 

x += 1

it should loop through and show it this way

0-0
0-1
0-2
0-3 ....

1-0
1-1
1-2
1-3 .... and so on.
```

Updates:

Trying this

if (x <= y and y < u[x].size)
then u[x][y]

Comment: I am interested in where/why you would want to use it. Why not just KISS?

Comment: Unless you can use recursion, there is no way to loop over an arbitrary sized array without a for/while loop.

Comment: 1. Why do you want to do it? 2. How about recursion?

Answer (score 0):

If recursive is available, this method might work.
If you cant use recursive, you might need another way to stack up the pile of if-else.

```
#a[2][3]

def loop(x,y,x_max):
  if x>0:
    print loop(x-1,y,x_max)
  elif y>0:
    print loop(x_max,y-1,x_max)
  return y,x

print loop(len(a)-1,len(a[0])-1,len(a)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
print(str(list(itertools.product('0123','0123')))
                        .replace("', '"," - ")
                        .replace("('","")
                        .replace("')","")
                        .replace("[","")
                        .replace("]","")
                        .replace(", ","\n"))
```

Output:

> > 0 - 0
> >         0 - 1
> >         0 - 2
> >         0 - 3
> >         1 - 0
> >         1 - 1
> >         1 - 2
> >         1 - 3
> >         2 - 0
> >         2 - 1
> >         2 - 2
> >         2 - 3
> >         3 - 0
> >         3 - 1
> >         3 - 2
> >         3 - 3